# Python - Convert shapefile lat-long value from Degree minutes seconds to Degree decimal

Tags: python, shapefile, polygon, latitude-longitude, geopandas

I am processing shapefiles in python using standard library functions like Python “shapefile” library and GeoPandas.
I have two shapefiles having the same projected co-ordinate system-> WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_44N.

But the first shapefile has lat-long values in **“Degree decimal”** format and the second shapefile has lat-long values in **“Degree minutes seconds”** format.

In order to proceed with further processing (merging the information from the two shapefiles) ***I need both shapefiles to be of the same format*** (either Degree decimal or degree minutes seconds format).

**SHAPEFILE 1(LAT-LONG VALUES):**

```
bbox =[300827.06, 2347377.51977153, 302414.939109026, 2348912.5], 
parts =[0], shapeTypeName =POLYGON ('number of points in shape ', 45)

bbox =[301663.127583958, 2345705.27205747, 303118.13, 2348567.5722892], 
parts =[0, 755], shapeTypeName =POLYGON ('number of points in shape ', 760)
```

**SHAPEFILE 2(LAT-LONG VALUES):**

```
bbox =[78.97802486855807, 21.102058250837672, 78.98699067762817, 21.107654743123476], 
parts =[0], shapeTypeName =POLYGON ('number of points in shape ', 28)

bbox =[79.1842653948201, 21.090100785102777, 79.18754905100815, 21.092718192209304], 
parts =[0], shapeTypeName =POLYGON ('number of points in shape ', 10)
```

Is there some function that can be applied on the shapefile for this conversion?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is that both shapefiles are in the same projection and not in the same format because

- the units of shapefile 1 ([EPSG:32644 (WGS 84 / UTM zone 44N)](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-utm-zone-44n/) projection) are METERS (X,Y and not  LAT-LONG VALUES)
- the units of shapefile 2 ([EPSG:4326 (WGS84)](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/) projection) are DEGREES (LONG-LAT VALUES and not LAT-LONG VALUES)

Therefore, using [pyproj](https://pypi.org/project/pyproj/) and [shapely](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/) ([shapely: Other Transformations](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#other-transformations)) here (but you can do it directly with [GeoPandas: re-projecting](http://geopandas.org/projections.html#re-projecting) or [Pyshp (shapefile)](https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/) in [Reproject a Polygon Shapefile using PyShp and PyProj](https://glenbambrick.com/2016/01/24/reproject-shapefile/))

```py
import pyproj
from functools import partial
from shapely.geometry import box
from shapely.ops import transform
project = partial(
      pyproj.transform,
      pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:32644'), # WGS 84 / UTM zone 44N
      pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326'))  # WGS 84 
# shapefile 1: polygon from bbox
poly1 = box(300827.06, 2347377.51977153, 302414.939109026, 2348912.5)
print(poly1.wkt)
POLYGON ((302414.939109026 2347377.51977153, 302414.939109026 2348912.5, 300827.06 2348912.5, 300827.06 2347377.51977153, 302414.939109026 2347377.51977153))
# convert to WGS84 degrees
print(transform(project, poly1))
POLYGON ((79.09633427339337 21.21722921309659, 79.09615638055131 21.23109069447097, 79.08086274438327 21.23091739451839, 79.08104206411475 21.21705603696002, 79.09633427339337 21.21722921309659))
```

Or the the reverse:

```py
project2 = partial(
  pyproj.transform,
  pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326'),  # WGS 84 
  pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:32644')) # WGS 84 / UTM zone 44N
# shapefile 2: polygon from bbox
poly2 =box(78.97802486855807, 21.102058250837672, 78.98699067762817, 21.107654743123476)
print(poly2.wkt)
POLYGON ((78.98699067762817 21.10205825083767, 78.98699067762817 21.10765474312348, 78.97802486855807 21.10765474312348, 78.97802486855807 21.10205825083767, 78.98699067762817 21.10205825083767))
# convert to WGS 84 / UTM zone 44N meters
print(transform(project2, poly2))
POLYGON ((290900.7896485617 2334765.616623482, 290908.6322568275 2335385.288572263, 289977.0655666431 2335397.106313651, 289969.1879661513 2334777.43181831, 290900.7896485617 2334765.616623482))
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the required conversion. But what I have observed is that both shapefiles have the same CRS. I used GeoPandas to read the shapefiles and the .crs attribute to display the current coordinate reference system. The output is as follows: CRS of shapefile 1 : {'init': u'epsg:32644'}
CRS of shapefile 2 : {'init': u'epsg:32644'}                                                                          But the transformation still works, could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: For me, It is a mistake because the projection of shapefile 2 is not epsg:32644